How to add a topic to rosbag without changing its topic Hz using Python?
I have a rosbag with 4 topics. I want to create a new rosbag with 2 additional topics with same Hz as extisting. I tried to read all topics in a loop using python and added 2 more topics.
Problem is, the original bag is of 600 secs and new bag is of 330 secs. But the number of messages remained same.
 bag = rosbag.Bag('/bag1.bag','r')
 outbag = rosbag.Bag('bag2.bag','w')

 for topic,msg,t in bag.read_messages():   
        if 'left' in topic:
            msg_l.header = msg.header
            outbag.write('/stereo_cam/left/camera_info', msg_l)           
            outbag.write(topic,msg)
            i+=1
        elif 'right' in topic:
            msg_r.header =msg.header
            outbag.write('/stereo_cam/right/camera_info', msg_r)
            outbag.write(topic,msg)
        else:
            outbag.write(topic,msg)
    # bag.close()
  outbag.close() 

When i run this, bag2 is only 334 secs compared to 600 secs of original bag1. I viewed the images and it looks like a 2x video.
What should I do to keep the frequency or bag2 same as bag1.
